# Finding most economical dimensions

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The question I am working on is:

*Find the most economical dimensions of a closed rectangular box of volume 8 cubic units if the cost of the material per square unit for (i) the top and bottom is 8, (ii) the front and back is 6 and (iii) the other two sides is 2.*

I decided to use Lagrange Multipliers to solve this.

The equations I set up to work with were:

$xyz = 8$

$C = 8(2xy) + 6(2xz) + 2(2yz) = 16xy + 12xz + 4yz$

Taking partial derivatives I have:

$\nabla C = \lambda\nabla V = <16y + 21z, 16x + 4z, 12x + 4y>$

$\lambda xyz = x(16y + 12z) = y(16x + 4z) = z(12x+4y)$

Solving for x and z, I get: $ x = y/3$ and $z = 4y/3$

Plugging into $xyz = 8$, $y = 2.621$. I then plugged that into the x and z equations to get $.874$ and $3.494$ respectively. None of these values are correct according to the WebWork.

Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without lagrange.

$V=8, V=xyz$

Top and Bottom: $xy=8$  sides: $xz=2$ front and back: $yz=6$

Want to minimize $C=8(2xy)+2(2xz)+6(2yz)$

$C= 16xy+4xz+12yz$

now, we have $xyz=8$ so $$z=\frac{8}{xy}$$

subbing into C gives $$C= 16xy+4x\frac{8}{xy}+12y\frac{8}{xy}$$

$$C= 16xy+\frac{32}{y}+\frac{96}{x}$$

Now computing partials and setting to zero,

$$C_x= 16y-\frac{96}{x^2}=0$$

$\rightarrow 16x^2y=96$

$$C_y= 16x-\frac{32}{y^2}=0$$

$16y^2x=32$

Multiplying by y and x respectively,

$16x^2y^2=32x=96y$

$\rightarrow x=3y$

using $C_x=0$ to solve $$16(3y)-\frac{32}{y^2}=0 \rightarrow y= (2/3)^{1/3}$$

from which x easily follows (x=3y) and knowing both x and y you can solve for z easily as well, in a few ways but may be easies to plug in x and y into 8=xyz.